# how to use RewriteCond based on system environment variable?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I have a system environment variable which I want to use in `mod_rewrite`. In my case `LOC` is set to `0`.

I want to route requests to port `8080` if `LOC` is `0`, else to port `9001`. Following rewrite condition does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:LOC} ^0
RewriteRule ^/app/ui(.*) http://app:8080/ui$1 [QSA,P,L]
RewriteRule ^/app/ui(.*) http://app:9001/ui$1 [QSA,P,L]
```

However, as every request is routed to port `9001`, the condition is never matched.

What's the better way to achieve this?

Comment: Can give us the content of your /etc/apache2/envvars file? How did you enbel/load it?

Comment: I fixed the issue as mentioned in a comment on your answer. I just export the env var in the /etc/apache2/envvars. works

Comment: So basically my answer that the variable was not loaded was right?

Answer (score 0):

> There are two kinds of environment variables that affect the Apache
>   HTTP Server.
>
> First, there are the environment variables controlled by the
>   underlying operating system. These are set before the server starts.

I assume LOC is a environment variables of the OS. And if you set this, after the web server was started apache do not know anything about it.

This explains why the condition is never matched.

Comment: it is set before

Comment: What OS do you have? 
If you turn on the rewrite logfiles what do they tell you? Wenn/Where is the env variable set?

Comment: it's a Debian Docker container. What I've done, is creating a /etc/apache2/envvars file to my needs, mount that file in the docker. Apart from its uglyness, it works. AFAIK there's just no way to get regular OS env vars in the apache conf files...

Comment: @Raf regular OS env vars are normally available in the Apache conf files.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond "%{ENV:LOC}" "=0"
RewriteRule ^/app/ui(.*) http://app:8080/ui$1 [QSA,P,L]

RewriteCond "%{ENV:LOC}" "!=0"
RewriteRule ^/app/ui(.*) http://app:9001/ui$1 [QSA,P,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond "%{ENV:LOC}" "=0"
RewriteRule ^/app/ui(.*) http://app:8080/ui$1 [QSA,P,L]

RewriteCond "%{ENV:LOC}" "=1"
RewriteRule ^/app/ui(.*) http://app:9001/ui$1 [QSA,P,L]
```

Comment: "if LOC is 0, else to port 9001" - "else" doesn't necessarily mean `1`.

Comment: @MrWhite Edited the answer.